# Angular routing with ngRoute doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to create a Single Page application with 2 views.

When I load the app is always shows me the first one of the 2 views regardless of what route I type in the browser. 
This is the javascript code:

```
  var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);
  appControllers.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $http) {
    var promise = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'restaurant.json'
    });
    promise.then(function(obj) {

      $scope.data = obj.data;
    });
  });
  appControllers.controller('InformationController', function($scope, $http) {
    var promise = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'restaurant.json'
    });
    promise.then(function(obj) {

      $scope.data = obj.data;
    });
  });

  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'appControllers']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/productlist.html',
          controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        when('/info', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/information.html',
          controller: 'InformationController'  
        })
    }]);
  app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $http) {
    var promise = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'restaurant.json'
    });
    promise.then(function(obj) {

      $scope.data = obj.data;
    });
  });
  app.controller('InformationController', function($scope, $http) {
    var promise = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'restaurant.json'
    });
    promise.then(function(obj) {

      $scope.data = obj.data;
    });
  });
```

I tried to change the order in which I define the 2 routes for the 2 view templates.
If I define the info template first the that template will be shown always and the other one will not be shown.
Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: Seems to load the templates just fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/uhl19fAbiHQbRp09hjzj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully functioning ngRoute:

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/a', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/a.html',
        controller: 'a'
    }).
    when('/av2', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/av2.html',
        controller: 'av2',
    }).
      when('/a3', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/a3.html',
        controller: 'a3'
      }).

      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/a'
      });
}]);
```

Try cross comparing that with your code and see if you find any differences. I think it may have to do with how you initiate your app very late into the script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'appControllers']);
```

Typically, bootstrapping your app is one of the most important things to do and should be at the top as a result.

Comment: That is not the case with AngularJS, config blocks will be executed before the application starts, regardless of where they are defined.